# Simplifying import of my package from package_name.module_name to package.name

Tags: python

After a lot of trial and error, I have developed my first python package and got it to the point where it is uploaded to `PyPI` test. I can then install it and import it in Spyder as intended. However, in order to use it, I need to call it using the package name and the module name in a format such as this:

```
from package_name.module_name import function_name
```

So if my package name is do_something, the module name is also named `do_something`, and the function name is `do_it_now`. So to get `do_it_now` (which is the function I wanted to package) to be accessible in Spyder, I need to do the following:

```
from do_something.do_something import do_it_now
```

My question is, can I simplify this so that a user only has to use a command like:

```
from do_something import do_it_now
```

Looking at my file structure, I do realize the package is named `do_something`, as well as another folder inside the package named `do_something`, and my .py file is also named `do_something`. I suspect these tiers in my file structure may be the cause, but when I tried to remove the `do_something` folder within the package and move my `do_something.py` and `__init__.py` files to the primary structure, I could not get my package to upload or subsequently install correctly.

Here is an outlay of my package structure:

Package Structure

[image: Package Structure]

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`from do_something import do_it_now` will attempt to import the **module** `do_it_now` from the **package** `do_something`. This will fail as there is no such module. If what you are trying to do is reduce the number of "."s the user uses in the import statement, you could try the following:

Add `from do_something import do_something` to `__init__.py`

Users could then use `import do_something` and access the function as `do_something.do_something.do_it_now`, or use `from do_something import *` and access the function through `do_something.do_it_now`.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  And you are correct that I was trying to reduce the number of "."s, or basically streamline the commands that were needed to get to the actual function.  My intent is to only have one or two functions, but be able to distribute via PyPI, so after researching it sounded like a package was the best way to go.  From what you mention, I have a correct structure and maybe there are no opportunities to instead do a `from package import function`.  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Indeed, Python does not make available this syntax available because it is ambiguous. Say you had a package with 2 submodules, each of which has a function named `do_it_now`, then `from package import do_it_now` does not specify which of the two available `do_it_now` functions should be used.

Answer (score 0):

According to [official_documentation](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) your structure should look like this.

```
/do_something
  /do_something
    __init__.py
    do_it_now.py
  setup.py
  LICENSE
  README.md
```

In your code then you will have just to import

```
import do_something
```

or

```
from do_something import do_it_now
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct on the structure.  I was looking at the package file that I used to upload to PyPI test, not the downloaded file after I pip installed.  However, this still requires me to from package_name.module_name import do_it_now

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you import do_something. Try this:

```
   import do_something
```

Or

```
   from do_something import *
```